# SQL QUERY USING POSTGRESQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT "stylists".* FROM "stylists" 
INNER JOIN "category_stylists" ON "category_stylists"."stylist_id" = "stylists"."id" 
WHERE category_stylists.category_id IN (1,2)
```

But I want to order the stylists by categories.

For example:

```
Stylists
id  |  Name
1      Sebastian
2      Jhon

Categories
id  |  Name
1      Wedding
2      Office

Stylist_Categories
id  | stylist_id |  category_id
1         1             1
2         2             1
3         2             2
```

So If I apply my query, I got both Stylists, but I need always order by  how many categories has the stylist. I mean in this example Jhon will be the first row because has the category_id 1 and category_id 2.

Result expected:

```
Stylists
id  |  Name
2      Jhon
1      Sebastian
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try counting categories for each stylist and order by it:

```
SELECT "id","name" from(
    SELECT "stylists"."id", "stylists"."Name",count(stylists.id) as cnt FROM "stylists" 
    INNER JOIN "category_stylists" ON "category_stylists"."stylist_id" = "stylists"."id" 
    WHERE category_stylists.category_id IN (1,2)
    group by "stylists"."id", "stylists"."Name")
order by cnt desc
```

Comment: No problem @sebaMelgar .